# How to solve this readline error in Veil module not found

Tags: python, module, kali-linux

I am getting a bash error, when using Windows, after running Veil.py module.

Please could you help me to work out how to fix this?

I have tried:

```
pip install readline
pip3 install readline
pip install pyreadline
```

However, none of these commands worked for me. Grateful for any pointers as to how to fix this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. To make it clearer, consider showing the error messages that you receive when you run each of the commands that you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the commands as root? Readline requires root access.

```
sudo pip install readline
```

Or, if on windows...

```
sudo pip install pyreadline
```

If that doesn't work you could try reinstalling pip first:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Please post the error messages you are seeing when you try!